# email client, algorithm for guessing email address based on few characters entered

Tags: algorithm, email-client, predict

We are writing an email client, and would like to have an algorithm guessing the intended email address based on the characters entered to the address line.
Something like Gmail's guessing based on the beginnings of the words in the address, as well as on frequency of use, or perhaps on when the address was used last. I don't know how they do it, but it works very well.

Is there a good public domain algo?
Or should we just make something up and improve as we go?

Answer (score 0):

it's just a simple jQuery/ajax post with database backend for figuring out the e-mail addresses.

so basically you attach a handler to an input box (i.e., keydown) - query your database, and then 'autofill' for suggestions. i.e., (borrowed from another source online)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        var txt = $("input").val();
        $.post("demo_ajax_gethint.asp", {suggest: txt}, function(result){
        $("span").html(result);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Start typing a name in the input field below:</p>
First name:

<input type="text">

<p>Suggestions: <span></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

and of course, then you'd make a file that output results based on what you input (the .asp or .php file).